# LDAP users synchronization

Tags: c#, synchronization, users, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to synchronize a users database between a piece of software and a ldap directory. Currently I'm thinking of three possibilities to keep the track of a specific user :

- Guid : it seems to be AD-specific but I guess other directories have an equivalent unique identifier. I can use a LDAP query `(&(objectClass=user)(guid=xxx))` to get the user.
- SamAccountName : also AD-specific and searchable via a LDAP query
- Path (DN) : should be consistent accross different LDAP providers. As I'm using the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace, I just have to do `var userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password);` to get the user

Are there other possibilities to achieve this ? What is the most reliable way to link the users from the database with the ones from the AD directory ? What would be the impact of these solution in term of performances ?

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sAMAccountName (or uid in most Unixy LDAPs IIRC) is not unique - its only unique within each domain.

If you want unique, you use the [ObjectGUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - if a user gets renamed or moved, this is the only bit that will remain constant. That means you need this if you have totrack a user getting a new username or moved to a different ou.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found an article that also recommend to use this solution http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1773.ldap-path-active-directory-distinguished-and-relative-distinguished-names.aspx#Object_Identity_and_Uniqueness